# Ibm Bluemix Retrieve and Rank

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, retrieve-and-rank

How do I Re-Rank the results generated by IBM Retrieve and rank service to get the optimal answer as i am unable to find any tutorial related to re-rank?

Comment: Questions like this one, about the Bluemix offering features, are best addressed on the IBM developerWorks Answers forum. Stack Overflow is a great place for Bluemix programming questions. See: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/smart-spaces/12/bluemix.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question. Do you mean the initial ranking by Retrieve and Rank of answers retrieved from Solr, or refining the ranking of already-ranked results? These specific links might be of help:

[Preparing training data](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/training_data.shtml). This covers how to train rankers.

[Reranking results](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/plugin_query_syntax.shtml). This covers how to refine the results produced by a ranker.

Comment: This might also be of help: [Tutorial Stage 6: Rerank the results](http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/retrieve-rank/tutorial.shtml#rank)